# git is pushing my commits but I'm not able to pull them on GitHub

Tags: git, github

GitHub won't recognize that I've pushed my files and I do not have the option to make a pull request.

I've taken my personal info out but these are my steps:

```
@penguin:~/bootcamp/Prework-study-guide$ git add -A
@penguin:~/bootcamp/Prework-study-guide$ git status
On branch feauture/add-css
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
modified:   assets/style.css
modified:   index.html

@penguin:~/bootcamp/Prework-study-guide$ git commit -m "added CSS to project"
[feauture/add-css 74c6492] added CSS to project
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 4 deletions(-)
@penguin:~/bootcamp/Prework-study-guide$ git pull origin main
Enter passphrase for key 
From github.com:
branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
:~/bootcamp/Prework-study-guide$ git push origin feature/add-css
Enter passphrase for key  
Everything up-to-date
```

I was expecting that the changes would be available to pull on GitHub.

Comment: Voting to close as typo, `feauture/add-css` vs `feature/add-css`

Answer (score 2):

You committed to a branch and pushed a different branch.

You committed to `feauture/add-css` (note the typo) and pushed `feature/add-css`. `feature/add-css` has no changes, so nothing was pushed: `Everything up-to-date`

The problem is made worse by spelling out the branch you're pushing. You should generally omit the branch you're pushing from, and the remote: `git push` should do the right thing. Exactly how this works depends on how you have [`push.default`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault) configured; the default is `simple` which will push to a branch with the same name on the remote. `git push` would push your current branch `feauture/add-css` to `feauture/add-css` on `origin`. It wouldn't fix the branch typo, but the changes would be pushed.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see the typo and your advice helped me solve my issue!